# Transition on anchor doesn't work properly

Tags: css, hover, refresh, anchor, transition

I have a transition on my anchors and every time I refresh the page, it just resets to default state of the anchor, and then it goes to the state I pre-defined with CSS.

When I put the transition into `:hover` it doesn't do this, but then I won't get a transition when I stop hovering over it.

```css
.button1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 3em;
  border: 0.16em solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 0.3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #DDDDDD;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.button1:hover {
  color: #FFB5B5;
  border-color: #FFB5B5;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" class="button1">div</a>
  <a href="#" class="button1">flex-box</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working? The animation works nicely when I hover over the buttons.

Comment: I would suppose it works as well, but I think he wants it to be permanently in the hover state after he has hovered over it, even after a page reload. That ain't going to work with CSS only, one needs javascript for that and a database or localStorage to save that, or one has to do something strange with keyframes and :visited, but I wouldn't encourage that.

Comment: No. I mean. When I load the page, the transition starts from the point where the anchors don't have any pre-defined styles.